# How can I avoid virtual inheritance when I have a "diamond" of interface classes?

Tags: c++, interface, multiple-inheritance

Suppose I have one base interface, and several other interfaces that derive from the base interface but also specify additional methods, and that no two methods from any two of the interfaces share names or signatures. So, for example, like this:

```
class Top
{
public:
    virtual ~Top() {}
    virtual void test() = 0;
};

class MiddleA : public virtual Top
{
public:
    virtual ~MiddleA() {}
    virtual void testA() = 0;
};

class MiddleB : public virtual Top
{
public:
    virtual ~MiddleB() {}
    virtual void testB() = 0;
};

class Bottom : public MiddleA, public MiddleB
{
public:
    void test() override
    {
        std::cout << "Invoked test()" << std::endl;
    }
    void testA() override
    {
        std::cout << "Invoked TestA()" << std::endl;
    }
    void testB() override
    {
        std::cout << "Invoked TestB()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

My intention is to specify one "base" type and have other interfaces that are different varieties of that base interface but also add other orthogonal functionality, and allow something that implements the functionality of the base interface to also implement one or more of those other interfaces on top.

Although virtual inheritance is clearly necessary to achieve this in the naive way I showed in my example, I'd like to avoid that overhead. Is there another way to achieve such an aggregation of functionality while avoiding virtual inheritance? I specifically need to have the middle interfaces also be children of the base interface so that a pointer to a middle class can still be used to access the base interface's functionality.

This is where Java's interfaces would be incredibly useful.

Comment: lolverhead, virtual inheritance hardly costs anything really

Comment: @Puppy I didn't specify this in the question but my particular use case involves OpenGL buffers, so every little pointer table look-up counts for something. Though I'm sure you're right, it won't make much of a difference, I'd rather use another "simple" solution if one exists. If there is no simple way to do this without virtual inheritance, I'll just accept that.

Comment: @Puppy I'm also honestly a bit confused as to why virtual inheritance is even necessary in this case. I always had thought virtual inheritance was used so that there wouldn't be multiple copies of the data members in the base class when using diamond inheritance. In this case, there are no data members.

Comment: @mebob: I don't get it. Why do you think virtual inheritance is necessary here? Just remove the `virtual`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl the snippet `Top *t = new Bottom();` when using those exact classes causes g++ to give me `error: 'Top' is an ambiguous base of 'Bottom'`

Comment: @mebob: OK. This snippet was missing from your example, so I guess I misunderstood the question, never mind.